# unit ark.service is not loaded properly:Exec format error

Tags: ubuntu

I will build a Ark Service and found something to help me on internet,but here is a error when I start it.

error:

```
Failed to start ark.service: Unit ark.service is not loaded properly:
Exec format error. See system logs and 'systemctl status ark.service'
for details.
```

ark.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=ARK Survival Evolved
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
StartLimitInterval=60s
StartLimitBurst=3
User=ark
Group=ark
ExecStartPre=/home/ark/steamcmd +login anonymous +force_install_dir /home/ark/server +app_update 376030 +quit
ExecStart=/home/ark/server/ShooterGame/Binaries/Linux/ShooterGameServer TheIsland?listen?SessionName=example -server -log
ExecStop=killall -TERM srcds_linux
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

```
ExecStop=killall -TERM srcds_linux
```

change to this:

```
ExecStop=/bin/killall -TERM srcds_linux
```

Answer (score 1):

Job for ark.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status ark.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

```
[Unit]
Description=ARK Survival Evolved
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
StartLimitInterval=60s
StartLimitBurst=3
User=ark
Group=ark
ExecStartPre=/home/ark/steamcmd +login anonymous +force_install_dir /home/ark/s$
ExecStart=/home/ark/server/ShooterGame/Binaries/Linux/ShooterGameServer TheIsla$
ExecStop=/bin/killall -TERM srcds_linux
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```